# Logrotate syslog and mysql error

Tags: mysql, syslog, rsyslog, logrotate

OS version: 20.04

When trying to manually logrotate, there are errors rotating syslog and mysql.

```
~$ sudo logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
error: rsyslog:4 unknown unit 'e'
error: found error in /var/log/syslog
, skipping
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log /var/log/mysql/error.log '
```

Here is my [rsyslog](https://pastebin.com/uVcdU3bu) and [logrotate.conf](https://pastebin.com/xCJXpi5i). EDIT: Here is the [mysql config](https://pastebin.com/0X7zWtbT).

`/etc/logrotate.conf` and everything in `/etc/logrotate.d` is 644.

The syslog problem is more urgent since it is kinda large at the moment. But any help on either of these problems would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure that in-line comments (`size 1G # add this line`) are permitted - the man page says *"Note that comments may appear anywhere in the config file **as long as the first non-whitespace character on the line is a #**."* Perhaps it's trying to parse the final `e` as a size unit (k,M,G)?

Comment: In your `rsyslog` you have a line `size 1G # add this line`. I would try removing `# add this line`. I don't know for sure but I think comments need to be on separate lines starting with `#`. Just a thought & something to try anyway.

Comment: Removing the comment seems to have fixed the rsyslog error. I don't remember touching these files ever but I must have when trying to set up logrotate at some point. Thanks guys. I'll add the mysql config as well.